# Как положить js в js

Tags: javascript

Суть: нужно, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку на странице появлялась карта доставщика (в данном случае, боксбери)! Но запихнув его в js он не срабатывает! Я любитель, может просто соринку не вижу!

```js
function btnClick1() {
  var Txt1 = "";
  var Txt2 = "";
  Txt1 = document.Test.bt.value;
  Txt2 = document.Test.bt.name;
  document.getElementById('ex1').innerHTML = "<div id='Dos_Inter'>" +
    "<script>" +
    "boxberry.openOnPage('boxberry_map');" +
    "boxberry.open();" +
    "function callback_function(result){ " +
    "document.getElementById('city').innerHTML = result.name;" +
    "document.getElementById('js-pricedelivery').innerHTML = result.price;" +
    "document.getElementById('code_pvz').innerHTML = result.id;" +
    "result.name = encodeURIComponent(result.name);" +
    "document.getElementById('name').innerHTML = result.name;" +
    "document.getElementById('address').innerHTML = result.address;" +
    "alert('усть телефон');" +
    "document.getElementById('workschedule').innerHTML = result.workschedule;" +
    "document.getElementById('phone').innerHTML = result.phone;" +
    "document.getElementById('period').innerHTML = result.period;" +
    "if (result.prepaid=='1') { " +
    "alert('Отделение работает только по предоплате!'); " +
    "}" +
    "}" +
    "</script>" +
    "<div id='boxberry_map'></div>" +
    "</div>";
}
```

```html
<div id="ex1"></div>
```

Comment: вы добавили весь код в функцию, а как вы данную функцию вызываете?

Answer (score 1):

https://www.danielcrabtree.com/blog/25/gotchas-with-dynamically-adding-script-tags-to-html

```js
function btnClick1() {
  document.getElementById('ex1').innerHTML = 
    "<div id='Dos_Inter'>" +
    "<div id='boxberry_map'></div>" +
    "</div>";
  var script = document.createElement("script");
  var inlineScript = document.createTextNode("console.log('dynamic script');");
  script.appendChild(inlineScript); 
  document.getElementById('Dos_Inter').appendChild(script);
}
```

```html
<div id="ex1"></div>
<button type="button" onclick="btnClick1()">Click</button>
```

Comment: Все равно не выходит!

Answer (score 0):

Так, как у вас, работать не будет.

Код должен быть примерно таким:

```
  document.getElementById('ex1').innerHTML = "<div id='Dos_Inter'><div id='boxberry_map'></div></div>";

  function callback_function(result){ 
    document.getElementById('city').innerHTML = result.name;
    document.getElementById('js-pricedelivery').innerHTML = result.price;
    document.getElementById('code_pvz').innerHTML = result.id;
    result.name = encodeURIComponent(result.name);
    document.getElementById('name').innerHTML = result.name;
    document.getElementById('address').innerHTML = result.address;
    alert('усть телефон');
    document.getElementById('workschedule').innerHTML = result.workschedule;
    document.getElementById('phone').innerHTML = result.phone;
    document.getElementById('period').innerHTML = result.period;
    if (result.prepaid=='1') { 
      alert('Отделение работает только по предоплате!'); 
    }
  }

  boxberry.openOnPage('boxberry_map');
  boxberry.open();
```

Но где вы вызываете callback_function с объектом result? Возможно её вызывает boxberry? Если нет, то в конец кода нужно добавить:

```
callback_function(передаваемыйОбъект);
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте создать `callback_function` в глобальной области видимости.

**Обратите внимание**, что в Вашем коде нигде не указан вызов или передача в виде параметра функции `callback_function`. Возможно, проблема кроется в этом.

В [документации Boxberry](https://boxberry.ru/upload/iblock/79d/%D0%98%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F%20%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F%20%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0%20%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B0%20%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B8.pdf) указано, что в `boxberry.open()` первым аргументом нужно передать callback функцию. Попробуйте указать `boxberry.open(callback_function)`

Рекомендую оформить код следующим образом, чтобы `callback_function` была объявлена явно, без динамического встраивания в HTML:

```js
function btnClick1() {
  var Txt1 = "";
  var Txt2 = "";
  Txt1 = document.Test.bt.value;
  Txt2 = document.Test.bt.name;
  document.getElementById('ex1').innerHTML = "<div id='Dos_Inter'>"+
    "<div id='boxberry_map'></div>" +
    "</div>";

    boxberry.openOnPage('boxberry_map');
    boxberry.open();
}

function callback_function(result) {
  document.getElementById('city').innerHTML = result.name;
  document.getElementById('js-pricedelivery').innerHTML = result.price;
  document.getElementById('code_pvz').innerHTML = result.id;
  result.name = encodeURIComponent(result.name);
  document.getElementById('name').innerHTML = result.name;
  document.getElementById('address').innerHTML = result.address;
  alert('усть телефон');
  document.getElementById('workschedule').innerHTML = result.workschedule;
  document.getElementById('phone').innerHTML = result.phone;
  document.getElementById('period').innerHTML = result.period;

  if (result.prepaid=='1') {
    alert('Отделение работает только по предоплате!');
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="ex1"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function btnClick1() {
  const injectScript = document.createElement('script');
  injectScript.text = '(()=>{alert("injectScript start...")})()';
  document.body.appendChild(injectScript);
}
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]